app.bsky.graph.getList returning no items?
I'm trying to use the Bluesky api to return the members of a created list. The reference at https://docs.bsky.app/docs/tutorials/user-lists#viewing-a-list says "call app.bsky.graph.getList to view a list and its members."
But when I just try a simple call using the widget on the reference page (https://docs.bsky.app/docs/api/app-bsky-graph-get-list), response.list is populated as expected, but response.items is empty.  This is true whether I use a list created by me or someone else and whether I use a bearer token or not. What am I doing wrong?
List parameter example: at://did:plc:4iq3wprtkim2tmlzabsj3dfo/app.bsky.lists/3kzghwrh2wy25
